# Post content to a webpage and return what it gets?

Tags: c#, webclient

I'm not very good with any networking type of things (as far as C# goes) but I need to post data (not get!) to a web url and then return what it outputs.

So far I'm using this for post and determining if it's logged in or not.

```
//credentials
        string username = textBox1.Text;
        string password = textBox2.Text;

        using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
        {
            byte[] data = Encoding.Default.GetBytes("username="+username+"&password="+password);
            client.Headers["Content-Type"] = "application/Json";
            try
            {
                var response2 = client.UploadData(base_url + "/users/authenticate", "POST", data);
                MessageBox.Show(Encoding.Default.GetString(response2));
            }
            catch { }
        }
```

Note: Error I'm getting is 400 bad request. Any ideas?

Comment: This depends entirely on the code that is executed on the server. If you cannot show us that code, we cannot help.

Comment: @dtb I'm trying to use the vine api. Content type is json.

Comment: Link to documentation?

Comment: @dtb here's better documentation, it's harder because I don't think vine has an official api doc. https://github.com/starlock/vino/wiki/API-Reference

Answer (score -1):

Looking at the vine code, I would say you need to send it JSON data instead of URL data. With something simple like that you can just write the string.

```
String jsonData = "{\"username\": \"" + username + "\", \"password\": \"" + password + "\"}";
```

**Updated to add encoding and be more strict with JSON data**

PHP's JSON decoder wants UTF-8 encoded data, so also change the encoding line to

```
byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonData);
```

Comment: That would make more sense although I'm still getting Bad Request using this method :/

Comment: Try it again with the updates. I don't know how strict PHP is with JSON encoding, so I made it very strict. Also PHP wants it with UTF-8 encoding, so I included that too. It's hard to say what vine wants looking at the API doc. It doesn't show any formatting of the authentication data, but the code is clearly looking for JSON data.